# I don't understand how to use 'infinitive' here.

Tags: infinitives

Here's a sentence I get mixed up.

> I was told that there will be a session **to actually perform** the skills we learn at the work shop.

I understand this sentence like this.

> I was told that there will be a session **that makes us actually perform** the skills we learn at the work shop.

Then, how exactly is the infinitive 'to actually perform' working here?

Comment: Right now, we're only going through the motions of various swimming strokes. Soon there will come a time to jump into the pool.  "time", "opportunity", "chance", "occasion" and their synonyms can take an infinitive complement.  There is no implication of being forced, merely of opportunity to do {x}.

Comment: @jihoon You can think of it as “(for us) to (actually) use”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree. Within **To actually perform** what stands out is the verb *perform*, then it is a verb phrase and it functions as a verb. The session is meant to put skills learnt in the workshop into practice. The second sentence doesn't sound natural or native-like. Native-likeness is the main feature of proficiency. In fact, **that makes us actually** not only is longer and more complicated, but it also sounds like the session is forcing you to do something. Plus, **that have us actually perform** makes a better sentence as it sounds like part of a whole teaching plan started in the workshop, however it still sounds much more formal than **to actually perform**. Last but not least, it is **in the workshop** as *workshop* is a training session rather than a public/famous place or a famous company/brand, then *at* is misplaced there. Lastly, **workshop** is a compound name and being so it is written altogether as one word only.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitive phrase "**to actually perform**" is there, it serves as a noun, a direct object to the verb "*makes*" (with *us* as the indirect object).

Some verbs when used with infinitive phrases as objects, cause the latter to lose the 'to' particle.  "Make" is one of those.  "Help" is another.  You can find more if you search for "infinitive as noun".